# SSL alert number 70 with TLSv1.3

Tags: nginx, tls1.3

```
# nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.21.4
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
```

I've configured nginx to support TLSv1.3.

```
ssl_protocols  TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
```

but i can't reach my host using TLSv1.3:

```
# openssl s_client -connect hostname.com:443 -tls1_3
CONNECTED(00000003)
140544753464640:error:1409442E:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert protocol version:../ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1543:SSL alert number 70
---
no peer certificate available
...
```

only TLSv1.2 works:

```
# openssl s_client -connect hostname.com:443 -tls1_2
CONNECTED(00000003)
...
```

Any host, like google.com or cloudflare.com connects fine using the same openssl command.

Of course, [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) test also confirms TLSv1.3 support not enabled.

[image]

I've also read [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1210619/can-t-get-tlsv1-3-to-work-with-nginx-1-14-0-and-openssl-1-1-1-on-ubuntu-18-04-4) and double-checked and I have one and only `ssl_protocols` line by `cd /etc/nginx; grep -rl "ssl_protocols"` which only outputs one file.

Comment: could you provide ssl chiphers do you use? I use `ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384";` and no problem at all

Comment: `ssl_ciphers  "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305";`. I've tried yours, same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found my issue, I've configured a default "catch all" server like this:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    ssl_reject_handshake on;
}
```

As specified in the docs here: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_reject_handshake

Problem is fixed by removing `ssl_reject_handshake on;` and instead return 444 on that server, like:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    ssl_certificate ssl/cert.pem;
    return 444;
}
```

This is a [known bug](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/2071) and should be fixed with [OpenSSL 1.1.1h](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/pull/13305)

Comment: I had the exact same error, but in my case, it was the certificate that was set to only use TLS 1.3. We generated a new cert where only TLS 1.2 was set, and since then it's been working perfectly